# VirtualBox ubuntu guest can ping out and access other IPs on bridged network but cannot be pinged or remotely accessed

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

**Aim:** To be able to access RStudio Server page from other internal PCs (all
   windows)

I barely know linux and everything I've done so far has been due to walkthroughs and the helpful responses to questions on this site.  If anyone is able to point me in the right direction of what to do next I'd be a happy chappy!

**Setup:**
Windows 7 host
VirtualBox 4.2.10
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop
CNTLM installed with pointer to proxy with hashed credentials
Two network connections: 1) NAT 2) Bridged to it's own NIC
NIC MAC address and Bridged adapter MAC address matched
IPv4 properties coded with static IP details
Static IP's details registered on dns server

**Details:**
Ping enabled in UFW and service restarted
Port 8787 enabled on UFW (sudo ufw allow 8787) 
The host can ping IP
The guest can ping host
The guest can ping my PC
my PC cannot ping guest

> Reply from myPCIP: destination host unreachable.

going to guestsIP:8787 gets

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Outputs

> *sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces*
>   auto eth0
>   face eth0 inet static
>   address 10.10.103.70
>   netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> *ifconfig*
>   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:fc:33:d5
>            inet addr:10.10.103.70  Bcast:10.10.103.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>            inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fefc:33d5/64 Scope:Link
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>            RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>            TX packets:109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>            RX bytes:2400 (2.4 KB)  TX bytes:15586 (15.5 KB)
>
> *sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules*
>   -A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j DROP
>   -A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j DROP
>   -A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j DROP
>   -A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j DROP
>   -A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: The aim on this was to be able to have other PCs within the business be able to access a program hosted on a vm, albeit on a desktop, seems fine to me - but happy to have it closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out most of my problems were arising from an incorrectly configured floor port.  Once this was correctly configured I was able to get the DHCP and gateway issues solved.